# Need to develop Protocol analyser for Abis?

Tags: c++, c

[Abis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_station_subsystem#BSS_interfaces) is the signals which are passed from [BTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_transceiver_station) to [BSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_station_subsystem#Base_station_controller) in mobile networks. The work they want to do is to collect the messages from BTS, analyse it to find some specific errors etc. So for doing these, I have to actually know how to do protocol analyser. the language which i am told is to use is c or CPP.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main stages on analysing data for any protocol:

- **Capturing or generating the network traffic**: For mobile networks, that generally involves *very* expensive receiver hardware - hardware that usually comes with its own analyser software that will be far better than anything you might code yourself. Base stations may allow for a way to monitor their operation and capture data. It is also theoretically possible to repurpose other hardware (e.g. a cell phone or a lab instrument), or to generate the data using a simulator.
- **Extracting the data of interest**: You need to extract and isolate the data for the protocol that interests you. Depending on the encapsulation and encryption properties of the network, that might be impossible for data captured in the wild - in that case you'd need something that would act as a node in the network and provide access to its inner workings.
- **Analysing the protocol of interest**: You need a piece of software that will not only implement the protocol, but that will provide far more extensive logging and error-recovery capabilities than any production implementations. That way it will be able to point out and handle misbehaving nodes.

If you intend to write a protocol analyser of your own, you need to aqcuire the protocol specification and code such an implementation. You should be warned that even the simplest protocols are in fact quite difficult to implement correctly.

Without more information on your development and target platforms, the source and format of the data and the resources that you have available, there is no way for us to provide more information.

PS: It would also help if your question contained an actual question that we could answer.

Comment: Thank you for the data. I will explain what the client told me. I am alone for this project, so it would be heavy work for me to complete this on my own.   Client said that there will be a usb port for conneccting a laptop or desktop to the system and thus with program that i am about to do will run and thus it will analyse the datas flowing through it. This is what they want.

Comment: @nos: I mentioned acquiring the specification in my answer. I suppose I should have also memntioned that it is normally *not* cheap.

Comment: @user585443 - isn't there already something like this that you can use?  Who makes the BTS & the BSC?